# Reinstalling Swinging Shower Door

Tags: doors, shower

I removed a shower door a while back to make it easy for our cat to get in and out of an unused shower.

Now I want to reinstall it but I can’t figure out what this plastic (shoe horn) piece does.

Any ideas?

I couldn’t find a brand name. Any ideas?

[image]

[image: what is this plastic part]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a temporary latch to stop the cat getting in.  Meant for doors to the outside world, for when you go on holidays etc.